# Difference between Databound & Databind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to know the difference between OnDataBound() & OnDataBinding() in Grid view in Asp.net webforms. When these events are triggered in the Page life cycle.

Comment: DataBind is not an event but its a method for Binding a server control with data.. There is a DataBinding event of a control which fires when a server control binds to a DataSource while the DataBound event occur AFTER the server control binds to a DataSource.

Comment: Then what is the difference between databinding & databound, as per you both are triggerring a server control binds to a DataSource

Answer (score 10):

`DataBinding` is triggered when the grid begins to bind data, but `DataBound` is triggered when all grid data is bound to the grid. Both of them are custom events of a grid control (or other data-bindable control) and executes in the page life cycle when the control events executes (in stage **postback event handling**).